# Ruby / Slim concatenation

Tags: ruby, slim-lang

I have a loop that checks the index against each value to build a breadcrumb, this data is passed in to a render using each slug as a separate hash in an array. Currently i'm getting a lot of "+" is not a method errors, but i have no idea how said line is meant to look in slim. The purpose of the line is to loop through the breadcrumbs array, adding the slug of the breadcrumb onto the previous one repeatedly, along with a slash before to create a usable url. Does anyone know the correct way to display this?

Code:

```
.c-fg
  ol.crumb
    - properties[:breadcrumbs].each_with_index do |breadcrumb, index|
      - url += "/" + breadcrumb[:slug]
      li
        a[href="#{url}" title="#"]
          = breadcrumb[:place]
```

Error Message:

```
undefined method `+' for nil:NilClass
```

Comment: Initialize `url` to an empty string. Right now, `url` is `nil` and you can't call `+=` on a `nil` object

Comment: Is it safe to assume you're using Rails? If so, Slim was basically made to be friendly to Rails shortcuts.  Use a link_to if this is the case.  It'll be more readable.
example:
  
` = link_to "How It Works", how_it_works_path, title: 'whatever' class: 'whatever'`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
.c-fg
  ol.crumb
    - properties[:breadcrumbs].each_with_index do |breadcrumb, index|
      - (url ||= '') << "/" << breadcrumb[:slug]
      li
        a[href="#{url}" title="#"]
          = breadcrumb[:place]
```

It’s always better to update the string inplace with [`String#<<`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.3/String.html#method-i-3C-3C) rather than produce an amount of temporary intermediate string objects with [`String#+`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.3/String.html#method-i-2B).

Comment: This works correctly, i guess the issue was like Arun said above, that url was set to to nil and i couldn't call += on it. Thanks for the help!

Comment: This has `url ||= ''` which defaults it to an empty string before appending things.